# Software to compare code runs

Tags: osx, c, debugging

To give a little context, I am testing a function (written in C) with the same input every time. In some runs it gives a result, and in others in gives a completely different one. Debugging is not a viable approach, because there are too many variables for me to keep track of alone.

Is there a program that records code runs, and then allows me to compare them side by side, in order to search for differences?

Comment: Do you know what output you expect for each input?

Comment: @CPerkins Yes, I have no doubts regarding that.

Comment: Do you have access to `diff`?

Comment: @CPerkins I do, but I am not seeing how it can be used for this purpose. I want to analyze the code as it is running, not compare the outputs.

Comment: I'm trying to understand here.  You're running a program, and the code calls your function once and gives a result, and then calls it again and you want to compare the first and second results?

Comment: It is something along those lines, yes. But I do not want to compare the results, since it is blatantly obvious that they are different. I want to compare the inner workings of the function. I could in theory do that using debugging, but as I have said there are way to many variables for me alone to keep track of.

Comment: Did you **really** say `Debugging is not a viable approach`?   Do you unit test? If not, do so. If `there are too many variables`, then break down the functionality and unit test each piece. I honestly don’t mean to be rude, but realize that this might sound so. If you want to develop software “properly”, then you need to learn how to do so. It might seem like extra effort to unit test, but – in truth – it will save you huge amounts of time & you will develop stable, robust, maintainable software, of which you can be proud. Please,, don't be a cowboy https://cdn.meme.am/instances/67259898.jpg

Comment: @Mawg, I eventually found the problem. It was a non-initialized variable, that sometimes was 0, sometimes was garbage, but that garbage messed up my final results. When I said too many variables, I meant structs within structs within arrays within linked lists within etc. There was absolutely no way I could have kept track of all the values of those structs using debugging, and even if I could, that wouldn't help me find the uninitialized variable. And yes, I unit test.

Comment: No offense, but I sense a contradiction here. Whatever unit tests you have obviously didn't cover that variable. However, I am glad to hear that you got it found and corrected. Now would be a good time to plan how to avoid this in future. Perhaps refactor your code? Does your programming language have a Linter?  And +1 for unit testing, far too few do https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/67259898.jpg  :-)

Comment: I am looking for [the same thing in PHP](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/76066/phpunit-extension-to-persist-and-auto-apply-buffer-changes). I know it exists, I just forgot the projects name and can't find it. If anyone knows...