# PHPUnit extension to persist and auto-apply buffer changes

Tags: php

There is this extension to PHPUnit that persist test results and after rerunning,
it asks you if those changes are correct (if any) or not (and updates accordingly).

It eliminates the need to manually adjust fixtures or data providers.

Unfortunately, I forgot the project's name and can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the lib I was looking for:

https://github.com/spatie/phpunit-snapshot-assertions

I missed the keyword "snapshot" while searching for it.